# zip library for native C++ with remove/modify capabilities

Tags: c++, zip, unzip

I am looking for a simple zip library (prefers without dll/lib) that will have zip modification capabilities.

The only option I've found so far to update/remove entries is by creating a temp file and writing everything to this temp, and than rename it to the original file.

Does anyone know a better way to update/remove zip entries without all that mess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libzip has support for replacing: [zip_replace(3)](http://nih.at/libzip/zip_replace.html) and deleting: [zip_delete(3)](http://nih.at/libzip/zip_delete.html) files in a zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to modify a zip file "in place".  Even Winzip and PKZip make copies.

Comment: technically true, but if you use a nice api and hide that fact away .. it just makes you feel good :)